# beforeTabChange event pause and continue (infinite loop)

Tags: javascript, extjs, coffeescript, infinite-loop, messagebox

I have tabs and I want to have some kind of validation before the tab changes, to save someone's work.

What is actually happening is the tab just passes right through my code and then on the callback the message box opens after the tab has changed. This is because of the asynchronous Message box that Extjs provides. Still I am unable to find a viable solution. Any help would be greatly Appreciated.

Also the code is written in coffee script. I have Edited the post my code is now stuck in a infinite loop.

Here is what i have now.

```
             beforetabchange:
                single:true
                fn:(tabPanel, newTab, oldTab, eOpts)->
                    if oldTab.isModified && oldTab.itemId != "linkedItemsTab" && oldTab.itemId != "capacityTab" && oldTab.itemId != "capacityTabEnterprise"
                        Ext.Msg.show
                            title: 'Warning'
                            message: 'You have unsaved changes in the <b>' + oldTab.title + '</b> tab, would you like to save them?'
                            buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL
                            icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION
                            fn: (btn) ->
                                if (btn == 'yes')
                                    tabPanel.suspendEvents()
                                    oldTab.saveRelease (release, isChanged) ->
                                    highlight "Your changes have been saved"
                                    oldTab.isModified = false
                                tabPanel.setActiveTab(newTab)
                                tabPanel.resumeEvents()
                        return false;
                    else if oldTab.isModified && (oldTab.itemId == "capacityTab" or oldTab.itemId == "capacityTabEnterprise")
                        Ext.Msg.show
                            title: 'Warning'
                            message: 'You have unsaved changes in the <b>' + oldTab.title + '</b> tab, would you like to save them?'
                            buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL
                            icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION
                            fn: (btn) ->
                                if (btn == 'yes')
                                    tabPanel.suspendEvents()
                                    me.saveActiveTabChanges()
                                    highlight "Your changes have been saved"
                                    oldTab.isModified = false
                                tabPanel.setActiveTab(newTab)
                                tabPanel.resumeEvents()
                        return false;
                    return true;
```